# How to provision AWS instances with cluster's IPs using Terraform and cloud-init?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, cloud-init, terraform0.12+

I am trying to configure the server and my application using `cloud-init` and its Terraform provider. Inside the initialization script I am using `write-files` to generate a configuration file which **needs to contain IPs of all the `aws_instances` generated by Terraform**; I tried (naively) to resolve with a template, something like this:

```
data "cloudinit_config" "test" {
  gzip          = false
  base64_encode = false

  part {
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content = templatefile("templates/cloudinit.yaml", {
      ip = aws_instance.test[*].private_ip  # <-- Trying to get the private_ip here
    })
  }
}


resource "aws_instance" "test" {
  count                       = var.num_nodes
  ami                         = "ami-00523c5e5a67c3b52"
  instance_type               = var.node_type
  user_data                   = data.cloudinit_config.test.rendered
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.public.id
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.web.id]
  tags = {
    Name = "Test${count.index}"
  }

  ebs_block_device {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"
    volume_size = var.hdd_size
    volume_type = "gp2"
  } 
}
```

Of course when I do `terraform plan` is telling me:

```
Error: Cycle: aws_instance.test, data.cloudinit_config.test
```

because there is a cyclic dependency between the private_ip of the machine (assigned at runtime) and the fact that i have to inject my cloud-init at the before running the machine.

**Is there any way to have the IP of all the EC2 instances injected inside the `cloud-init` script?**

---

**EDIT: add piece of `cloud-init` script**

```
write_files:
- content: |
    timeout=200
    nodes=${jsonencode($ip)}
  path: /etc/zerk/main.config
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use DNS names instead of IPs have a look at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#private_dns

Otherwise, You can use ugly, but straightforward https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#private_ip

### EDIT: added example:

```
variable "private_ips" {
  type = list
  description = "Additional private IPs associated with EC2 instances" 
}

# Notes, number of IPs should match number of nodes
# IPs should be within CIDR range of the VPC
private_ips = ["172.10.32.1", "172.10.32.2", "172.10.32.3"]

data "cloudinit_config" "test" {
  gzip          = false
  base64_encode = false

  part {
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content = templatefile("templates/cloudinit.yaml", {
      ip = var.private_ips
    })
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "test" {
  count                       = var.num_nodes
  user_data                   = data.cloudinit_config.test.rendered
...
  private_ip = element(var.private_ips, count.index)
...
}
```

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#vpc-private-ipv4-addresses)

Comment: Thanks, that is not an answer to me. please have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer in particular _answer the question_ and _provide context for links_ . Can you provide at least a working example like, I did in my question?

As I _already wrote in the question_ we cannot use resource attributes that are populated **after** the instance creation because the `cloud-init` script will be prepared & injected **before** the instance creation. Terraform is giving errors.

Comment: @zambotn then answer the question: can You use DNS names instead of IPs ? (OR maybe even better; could You share, at least partially cloudinit script?)

Comment: i added the piece of `cloud-init`. I _may_ add the DNS names but they are built using pattern `ip-<private-ipv4-address>.<region>.compute.internal` (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html). Your suggestion is to create manually all IP addresses beforehand so instead of changing `var.num_nodes = 100` i should populate a list with 100 IP addresses? while it should work it doesn't look like a clean solution. It may require lots of manual work (or another template engine on top) to build a bigger cluster.